# Calling a Java function from C++ on Android over JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am calling **C++ from Android with JNI** and so far it works. Now I need in that C++ function some functionality from Java and try to call back to Java from C++. I checked various solutions on stackoverflow and other sources on the net but I somehow just couldn't get it working.

I always get the following Exception "`W/dalvikvm(358): JNI WARNING: can't call Lcom/main/Main;.message on instance of Lcom/main/Main;`"

Can anyone give me any advice on this ? Did I miss something, oversee something or have just plain wrong code ?

Here is the Java part that I want to call from C++:

```
public class Main extends Activity  
{   
    public  native  String  JNIInit();

    String message(String text)
    {   text = text + "from java";
        return text;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

This is the **C++** function that I can successfully call from Java but from which I cannot call back to Java:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_main_Main_JNIInit(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{   jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF("From jni");
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/main/Main");
    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "message", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, method, jstr);
    return env->NewStringUTF(str);
}
```

PS: I know there are several threads on this topic here, but I couldn't get it working anyway. There must be something that I just miss, and I simply can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Did you check to see if the method signature that you have is right? You can do a javap on your class to see if it is right.

Comment: OK, I just verified to see that it is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `FindClass`, can you try using: `(*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);`

Comment: That did it. This was driving me crazy and it finally works now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

you have use
create an empty string in c++ and also pass the empty string from java from the method

```
 jString pSrc = (*env)->GetString(env,source, 0);
```

// Here source is the empty string u are passing from the java method 
now u copy the string into source

```
 (*env)->String(env, source, pSrc , 0);
```

and in the end use

```
(*env)->ReleaseString(env,source, pSrc , 0);
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question - he couldn't even get a reference to the class.