# Android NDK: No implementation found for native xxxxxx

Tags: android, android-ndk

I do a project in using Tess-two, i want to use the method `pixConvertRGBToLuminance`, but it always the error:

```
No implementation found for native Lcom/googlecode/leptonica/android/Pix;.nativePixConvertRGBToLuminance:(I)I.
```

My code Java is:

```
public static Pix pixConvertRGBToLuminance(Pix pixs){
    if (pixs == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Source pix must be non-null");

    int nativePixd = nativePixConvertRGBToLuminance(pixs.getNativePix());

    return new Pix(nativePixd);

}
```

My code .cpp is:

```
jint Java_com_googlecode_letonica_android_Pix_nativePixConvertRGBToLuminance(JNIEnv *env,
    jclass clazz, jint nativePixs){

PIX *pixs = (PIX *)nativePixs;

LOGE("------------------>Failed to find native pixConvertRGBToLuminance File");
PIX *pixd = pixConvertRGBToLuminance(pixs);
return (jint) pixd;
}
```

The original code of Leptonica is :

```
PIX * pixConvertRGBToLuminance(PIX *pixs)
{
  return pixConvertRGBToGray(pixs, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}`
```

so why I always have the fault?Thx.

Comment: Is your Pix class in the com.googlecode.letonica.android package?

Answer (score 0):

Another question where the answer is C++ name mangling - declare your function as `èxtern "C"`

Comment: It doesn't work, i use the project tess-two as a library. For other methods that work, there is no extern "C" as well. I tried to compile the method 'rankFilter', it works wellm but this class never worked, even other methods. i really don't why. is it possible that the mk file wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
extern "C" jint Java_com_googlecode_letonica_android_Pix_nativePixConvertRGBToLuminance(JNIEnv *env,
    jclass clazz, jint nativePixs){

PIX *pixs = (PIX *)nativePixs;

LOGE("------------------>Failed to find native pixConvertRGBToLuminance File");
PIX *pixd = pixConvertRGBToLuminance(pixs);
return (jint) pixd;
}
```

Refer [Calling a Java function from C++ on Android over JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428001/calling-a-java-function-from-c-on-android-over-jni)